# Visual Studio Find/Replace Current selection color change?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio I can go to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors and can have search results highlighted by changing Find Match Highlight.

When doing find/replace, the current row that will have the replace applied, is very near the same colour as every other find result. Which makes it difficult for me to see what line I'm on.

Is it possible to modify the foreground and/or background of the currently "selected"/active row when doing Find/Replace independent of the "Find Match Highlight" colour?

"Find Scope Highlight" doesn't seem to do this, because on my system that is set to black and my Find Highlighting is Red and the current Find row is a *slightly* different shade of red.

Comment: have you tried https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor

Comment: @Peter And what do I need to change the colour of? The built in tool to modify colours is easy to use, I just don't know what I'm changing.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color for background of the selected line from a find in Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Highlight Current Line and change the Item background.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is actually the same as "Selected Text" (2nd entry after Plain Text).

If you want to toy with the colors of the items that are colored when you set the cursor, you want to look into "Highlighted Definition"/"Highlighted Reference", definition would be `int  *counter*;` reference would be `*counter* = 0;`.

If you select something, then VS finds all the occurrences of the same string, indepent if its a variable or something else, you can change the "Selection Match Editor Highlight".